# Shiny selectizeInput with value and label fields

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, selectize.js

I want to customize a `selectizeInput` in `shiny`, similar to this example from https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/. The value and label should be different and it should be possible to select more than 1 entry and add new entries (using the `create = TRUE` option). I have tried with `selectizeInput` und `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets` but cannot get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look here for some examples: [shiny selectize examples](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/selectize-examples.html)

Most of the advanced options are set via the options. A minimal example without color is here:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput('myInput',
                 label='Select',
                 choices=c('first choice' = 'c1'),
                 multiple = TRUE,
                 options = list(create = TRUE))  
)
```

Answer (score 4):

The option `render` allows to set the items in HTML. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

itemValues <- c("foo", "bar")
itemNames <- sprintf("<span style='background-color:springgreen'>%s</span>",
                     itemValues)
items <- setNames(itemValues, itemNames)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("id", "Label", choices = items, 
                   options = list(render = I("
  {
    item: function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; },
    option: function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; }
  }")))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

[image]